# MVC 4 Action method nullable string parameter required error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have following code in my MVC4 project (vs2010), I am new to this MVC stuff. please help

```
   public ActionResult ViewAlbum(string id)
    {
            var searchStr = id;
            TB_ALBUM_MASTER tb_album_master = db.TB_ALBUM_MASTER.Single(t => t.ALBUM_NAME.ToLower() == searchStr.ToLower());
            if (tb_album_master == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tb_album_master);

    }`
```

It gives me this error on action method definition line

> Error 131 The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

Here is My RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling this action method? Show us that code as well.

Comment: @SBirthare browsing to localhost:1507/albums/viewalbum/Album%20One

Comment: shouldn't it be `localhost:1507/Albums/ViewAlbum/Album%20One`?

Comment: Try localhost:1507/albums/ViewAlbum/AlbumOne, works for me. Or localhost:1507/albums/ViewAlbum?id=AlbumOne

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, are you sure you get error at method definition line. Can you place a breakpoint on var searchStr = id; and see if it hits.

Comment: How do you define id in your model? `string id` or `string? id`?

Comment: @SBirthare Though, there was nothing wrong in the code. I fixed it by defining new route. and yes! Break point got hit every time I debugged the code.

Comment: @teovankot I used %20 for space. I had my records with value Album One.

Comment: @nevra  I used Database first approach to create models. So I didn't touch any of the code generated by EF 6 for me. Though I guess its still like `string Id`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came to know that I needed to fix my RouteConfig.cs to enable my new route where id parameter is going to be a string and it can be null.

So here is my fix: Here is my new RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Defaults",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

(Please suggest me if its wrong way to handle such exception or if there are any other fixes for this.)

Comment: I am still not sure why adding this explicit route solved your problem. First i was not able to reproduced it on a default application. Second even if you were able to reproduce, what difference second route make. The first route is same, keeping id optional.

Answer (score 0):

This error message:

> Error 131 The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

Indicates you are trying to use string as a parameter to System.Nullable.  System.Nullable is only for value types, which string is not, it's a reference type (and already nullable).

This would be the case if you have written `Nullable<string>` or `string?` somewhere.  This has nothing to do with routing, so your claim that changing your route fixed the problem does not seem possible.

To fix this problem, you first need to identify where you are trying to create a nullable string, then remove the nullable from from it.

Comment: I got your point, but I created my edmx model from database using add model wizard. It has not defined any string like string?` or Nullable<string>`. And by changing route i am able to route to that specific action method.